# Why does Neighbor Discovery Protocol have to monitor upper-layer protocols?

Tags: tcp, ipv6, layer3, layer4, rfc

While reading the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861) of NDP I wondered, why it is necessary to monitor upper layer traffic in order to know if a neighbor is reachable, e.g. a TCP ACK.

I do get the IPv6 packet anyway, so I know it's reachable without having to bother about TCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does it say it is "*necessary to monitor upper layer traffic?*" [*RFC 4861, Neighbor Discovery for IP version 6 (IPv6)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861) actually says:

> When available, this upper-layer information SHOULD be used.

[*RFC 2119, Key words for use in RFCs to Indicate Requirement Levels*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119) defines the term SHOULD:

> 3. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
>    particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
>    carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

The use of upper-layer protocol information deals with Neighbor Unreachability Detection. This deals with neighbors that have already been discovered, but something may have gone wrong. For instance, a the neighbor's NIC was swapped, so the MAC address for the neighbor has changed. You need to make sure that the forward path works. See [*7.3.1. Reachability Confirmation*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861#section-7.3.1), specifically:

> The receipt of a solicited Neighbor Advertisement serves as
> reachability confirmation, since advertisements with the Solicited
> flag set to one are sent only in response to a Neighbor Solicitation.
> Receipt of other Neighbor Discovery messages, such as Router
> Advertisements and Neighbor Advertisement with the Solicited flag set
> to zero, MUST NOT be treated as a reachability confirmation.  Receipt
> of unsolicited messages only confirms the one-way path from the
> sender to the recipient node.  In contrast, Neighbor Unreachability
> Detection requires that a node keep track of the reachability of the
> forward path to a neighbor from its perspective, not the neighbor's
> perspective.  Note that receipt of a solicited advertisement
> indicates that a path is working in both directions.  The
> solicitation must have reached the neighbor, prompting it to generate
> an advertisement.  Likewise, receipt of an advertisement indicates
> that the path from the sender to the recipient is working.  However,
> the latter fact is known only to the recipient; the advertisement's
> sender has no direct way of knowing that the advertisement it sent
> actually reached a neighbor.  From the perspective of Neighbor
> Unreachability Detection, only the reachability of the forward path
> is of interest.

Comment: So in summary: because you need to know the link is working in both directions.